# Aligning columns of the matrix with the labels on r markdown

Tags: matrices, rmarkdown

I am unable to align the columns of my matrix with the column labels. I have attached my code below along with the output. Can someone help me fix this pls ? I want to align 0, 1, 2, 3 to the respective columns

```
<div class="math">
\[
\begin{array}{ccc} &
\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{array}
\\
P=\begin{array}{cccc}
0 \\
1 \\
2\\
3\end{array}
&
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 0.2 \\
0 & 0.5 & 0.4 & 0.1 \\
0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)\end{array}
\]
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: `\begin{array}{ccc}` should be `\begin{array}{cc}` and, 3 rows later, `P=\begin{array}{cccc}` should be `P=\begin{array}{c}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do with the tools of the package `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,siunitx}    

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row=\color{blue}, code-for-first-col = \color{blue}}

$P = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
  & 0 & 1   & 2   & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 0.2 \\
1 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.4 & 0.1 \\
2 & 0 & 0   & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
3 & 1 & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
   
\bigskip
With the columns \verb|S| of \verb|siunitx|:

\medskip
$P = \begin{pNiceArray}{cSSS}[first-row,first-col]
  & {0} & {1}   & {2}   & {3} \\
0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 0.2 \\
1 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.4 & 0.1 \\
2 & 0 & 0   & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
3 & 1 & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
\end{pNiceArray}$    

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers should be aligned on their decimal markers, I suggest you employ the `dcolumn` packaga and its `D` column type for 3 of the 4 columns in the right-hand side `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn} % for 'D' column type
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ c @{} c } % "outer" array: 2 columns, no sep. 
& 
   \begin{array}{c *{3}{d{1.1}} } 
      0 & 1 & 2 & 3
   \end{array}
\\
  P=\begin{array}{c}
       0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 
    \end{array}
&
  \left(
  \begin{array}{c *{3}{d{1.1}} }
     0 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 0.2 \\
     0 & 0.5 & 0.4 & 0.1 \\
     0 & 0   & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
     1 & 0   & 0   & 0
  \end{array}
  \right)
\end{array} % end of "outer" array
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Error: LaTeX failed to compile extra.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See extra.log for more info.
Execution halted . I keep getting this error message am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @AneethaDaniels - You report "See extra.log for more info." Well, what does `extra.log` have to say?

Comment: I did everything they had suggested but I keep getting the same error. But thanks a lot for this. I'll work on it and try and find the issue

Comment: @AneethaDaniels - You've mentioned that you couldn't compile a test file, but you haven't provided any error messages, or even an indication  that the errors are related to the code provided above. It's not easy to provide help in a no-information state.